PostgreSQL default value don't work in Spring/Hibernate application
There is an application on Spring/Hibernate. I am using the PostgreSQL-database. I created the table with this script:
create table competence_aud
(
    ctl_validfrom     timestamp(6) not null default current_timestamp,
    pk                int8,
    employee          int8,
    competence        int8,
    lastupdatedwhen   timestamp(6)
);

I assume, that, if the date is NULL, then the current date will be inserted into the table (because I use current_timestamp).
Then, in the code I created this class:
@Entity
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Table(name = "competence_aud")
@SourceEntity(schema = Schemas.core, table = "competence")
public class CompetenceAudEntity implements Record<Long> {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "pk")
    private long pk;

    @Column(name = "ctl_validfrom")
    private Timestamp ctlValidfrom;

    @Column(name = "employee")
    private Long employee;

    @Column(name = "competence")
    private Long competence;

    @Column(name = "lastupdatedwhen")
    private Timestamp lastupdatedwhen;

    @Override
    public Long getObjectId() {
        return pk;
    }

    public void setLastupdatedwhen(Timestamp lastupdatedwhen) {
        this.lastupdatedwhen = lastupdatedwhen;
        this.ctlValidfrom = lastupdatedwhen;
    }

}

I start the application. And in the case, when I get NULL value for a date, I see the error in the logs:
o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : ERROR: null value in column "ctl_validfrom" of relation "competence_aud" violates not-null constraint
  Detail: Failing row contains (null, 22, 474, 546, null).

I think, the current_timestamp does not work at all :-(
Can you explain, why this is happening? How I must change my code?

It will only insert the default value if there is no explicit value for the column. Here you have an explicit null value for the column. What you want is to use an @DynamicInsert and/or @DynamicUpdate. With that columns with a null or not explicitly set value will not be part of the insert and your default value will take effect. However there is now a discrepancy between your DB and the entity as that won't have the value unless you forcefully read it again from the DB.

When the CompetenceAudEntity object is inserted into the table, Spring will generate something like the following sql code:
insert into competence_aud (ctl_validfrom, pk, employee, competence, lastupdatedwhen) values (null, 22, 474, 546, null)

Since Spring explicitly passes null in the ctl_validfrom field, current_timestamp does not fire and does not generate a value automatically.
To solve your problem, I suggest generating the current time before writing to the database. To do this, use the annotation org.hibernate.annotations.CreationTimestamp
example:
@Entity
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Table(name = "competence_aud")
@SourceEntity(schema = Schemas.core, table = "competence")
public class CompetenceAudEntity implements Record<Long> {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "pk")
    private long pk;

    @Column(name = "ctl_validfrom")
    @CreationTimestamp
    private Timestamp ctlValidfrom;

    @Column(name = "employee")
    private Long employee;

    @Column(name = "competence")
    private Long competence;

    @Column(name = "lastupdatedwhen")
    private Timestamp lastupdatedwhen;

   ...

}

